# Which SQL Server spatial data type to use for UK data in SQL Server?

Tags: coordinate-system, sql-server, united-kingdom

Which spatial data type should be used for UK data in SQL Server?, i.e. GEOMETRY or GEOGRAPHY?

I'm aware of [OS National Grid](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/support/the-national-grid.html) and my understanding is it's an X/Y coordinate system, covering from Sicily Isle to Shetlands.

So it looks like best option would be GEOMETRY

But if we store our data in GEOMETRY, will it work with things like Open Street Maps, e.g. using LeafletJS with OSM base, and our data as overlays

Answer (score -2):

You should use GEOGRAPHY and yes it will work with both Open Street and Google Maps.

Comment: please [edit] your answer to include more information. Why is geography better? Your answer reads more like a comment with nothing to back up your statement. Our site works better with more detailed and thought out answers hopefully with references to back up your claims.